# Android Open Mobile API Release Difficulties

Tags: android, nfc, securityexception, open-mobile-api, secure-element

I am using the "org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar" file from SDK. I copied it to my libs folder and added the dependency like this

#### Case #1: working fine (in debug mode)

In app Gradle file I have:

```
provided files('libs/org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar')
```

#### Case #2: not working (in release mode - without minifyEnabled)

In app Gradle file I have:

```
compile files('libs/org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar')
```

In case #2 I get the following exception:

> (java.lang.SecurityException: Access Control Enforcer: no APDU access allowed!)

What could cause the problem?

Comment: Could you clarify why you use "compile" for release build while you use "provided" for the debug build? Are you able to access the secure element in the debug build?

Comment: I only have access to secure element when I use "provided" in debug mode

Comment: But why don't you use provided for the release build as well?

Comment: when I change build type from debug mode to release mode, I get the following exception:(java.lang.SecurityException: Access Control Enforcer: no APDU access allowed!)

Comment: This is effectively the third time you've asked the same question. Please do not keep re-asking the same question over and over again; that is abusive of our resources. If you want to improve your question or add new details, you can [edit] it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to use the "provided" scope in your build.gradle file for both your debug and your release build:

```
dependencies {
    [...]
    provided files('libs/org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar')
}
```

**UPDATE**

"provided" is obsolete and has been replaced with "compileOnly", so for current gradle versions, you need to use (as commented by [TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3066295/tt)):

```
dependencies {
    [...]
    compileOnly files('libs/org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar')
}
```

Moreover, you need to have a uses-library entry in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.simalliance.openmobileapi"
              android:required="true" />
```

However, since you got a `SecurityException` with the reason "Access Control Enforcer: no APDU access allowed!", this is a clear indication that linking to and using the system-provided Open Mobile API library worked as expected and that you successfully connected to the SmartcardService system service on your device. Consequently, you seem to have your build working as expected.

Therefore, the `SecurityException` already clearly tells you what the problem is:

> Access Control Enforcer: no APDU access allowed!

This means that the access control list on the secure element is not properly configured. Since your debug build works, you probably did register the certificate for your debug environment with the ARA applet (and/or the ARF file) on the secure element. However, release builds are not signed with that same debug keys (certificate). Instead, they are signed with the release keys (certificate) that you chose when selecting "Generate Signed APK..." in Android Studio. Therefore, you have two options:

1. Add the release certificate to the list of allowed applications for your applet on the secure element.
2. Change access conditions on the secure element to ALLOW ALL in order to allow access to any applet from any device app.

Depending on your secure element, you would typically need to update the ARA (GlobalPlatform Access Control) applet (AID `A00000015141434C00`) or the access rules file (ARF) located in a PKCS#15 application (AID `A000000063504B43532D3135`) or in the SIM file system with the new access conditions.

Comment: When using Android studio "Open Mobile API (API 21)" as "Compile Sdk Version" under File->Project Structure->Modules you must leave out the provided scope in build.gradle

Comment: **"`provided` is obsolete and has been replaced with `compileOnly`"**.  It will be removed at the end of 2018.

*For more information see:*
http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html